# Using the count of coincidence from a regexp as replacement text?

Tags: regular-expressions

I have an org-mode file with more than 12000 footnotes (maybe less), I was cleaning it and found that after the conversion some footnotes weren't converted to org-mode footnotes, so I had to manually make them footnotes.

The thing is, since that addition the reference number inside the square brackets must be re-done otherwise I will end with repeated numbers, like: `[12] ... [12]` or `[10678] ... [10678]`. Is there a way to build a regexp that look for all numbers inside square brackets and replace the text inside them with their respective coincidence number (?) for instance: `[12]` is the coincidence number 10 and this other `[12]` is coincidence number 11 so `[12] ... [12]` becomes `[10] ... [11]`?

**especial petition:** if you are going to post an elisp snippet that solves this problem, please, please, please, comment it on detail because I want to learn elisp too!

Comment: They are references, so must we expect that the number references to somewhere? I.e. in your situation, there are 4 occurrences of `[12]`, two of them (reference + footnote) should be renamed `[10]` and the other two should be renamed `[11]`? That makes the question much more difficult than the way it is currently phrased!

Comment: How many of your references are duplicates? If not too many, I'd suggest de-duplicating them by hand, using a different namespace (e.g. `[12-2]`) to avoid the numbering issue.

Comment: Using the `[fn:name]` syntax rather than hand numbering is a better long term solution.

Comment: The references will be worked on separate files to make things easy. They aren't many, though I'm worried about how will `[12-2]` looks after exporting the document ...

Comment: You're right, [12-2] is not recognised as a footnote, my bad. Andrew Swann's solution is the best, and the notes should be auto-numbered by the org exporter in this case.

Comment: Also, if you drop your requirement about learning Elisp, you can probably employ keyboard macros together with the keyboard macro counter (if that is what it's called, see the manual) and `C-u C-s' within a macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To re-number **all** footnotes starting from 1 you can use `M-x query-replace-regexp` (or, if you're feeling confident, just `M-x replace-regexp`) and type in

`\[[0-9]+\]` as the regexp to replace and

`[\,(1+ \#)]` as the replacement.

Here `\#` is the match count *starting from zero*, so I used `\,` and a lisp form which adds one to it.

To get (most of) this information, press `C-h f replace-regexp` and hit `RETURN`.

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly! Is just a matter of separating the footnotes and putting it on a different file before using `replace-regexp`!